# Multiple moving sprites in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am currently making a game for android using Java in Eclipse. I am having a problem moving multiple sprites at once on the screen. Here is some code to show you what I have done so far.

Here is the run method for the thread in the game. It calls an onDraw method to draw the sprites on the screen. These are both in a class that extends SurfaceView and implements Runnable.

```
public void run() {
        long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
                long startTime;
                long sleepTime;
        while (running) {
        Canvas c = null;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
        c = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        synchronized (getHolder()) {
        onDraw(c);

        }
        }  finally {
        if (c != null) {
        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

}
        sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime); 
        try {
               if (sleepTime > 0)
                      Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
               else
                      Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
}

}
```

Here is said onDraw method. There are 2 fret buttons at the bottom left and right, like in a rhythm game. And what I am trying to do is create a 'badfret' that will appear at the top and move downwards. Some of this code is patched together from other programs and some is my own.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
    badguy = true;

if(badguy == true){
    if(switch_sides = true){
        badfret1.move(canvas,30,40);
        badfret1.update(canvas);
    }
    if(switch_sides = false){
        badfret2.move(canvas,500,40);
        badfret2.update(canvas);
    }
}



    fret1.update(canvas);
    fret2.update(canvas);
}
```

Here is code from the badfretSprite class which I felt would be most appropriate to the question. badfretSprite class inherits from a higher Sprite class I made.

```
Bitmap bmp;
int xSpeed = 0;
int ySpeed = 5;

public badfretSprite(GameView gv, int x1, int y1) {
    super(gv, x1, y1);
    this.bmp = gv.getFret();
}

public void move(Canvas canvas,int xpos,int ypos) {
    x = xpos;
    y = ypos;
    x+=xSpeed;
    y+=ySpeed;
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x,y, null);
    }
```

So at the moment only one sprite is created at the top and does not move, I have managed to make it move but only one has done so.

Please ask if there are any other methods or snippets of code you would like to see.

```
public void update(Canvas canvas) {
    move(canvas,xSpeed,ySpeed);
}
```

Comment: can you post the update methods for your objects.

Comment: I have added it to the end.

Comment: I don't see a point where you call this for the badFretSprites you create

Comment: Thank you that means they move now, now I need to solve the multiple moving sprites problem

Comment: I have edited the original post changing where I create my sprite objects and added in the update method calls.

Comment: Did that solve your problem or are still having issues?

Comment: That solved it, I now have one badFretSprite being created and moving down the screen.

Comment: Ok then I'll add that as an answer and a note on some of your code that should be changed, it'll make things easier in the long run for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point where you update the badFretSprites.

Also you should really separate your drawing and update logic, the game loop should look like this

```
    synchronized (getHolder()) {
        update();
        onDraw(c);
    }


    update(){
        for every object
            object.update()
    }

    onDraw(){
        for every object
            object.draw()
    }
```

So you should only update the position in the update method and only draw in the draw method, once your app becomes more complex it'll be easier to manage, add to and debug.